# Printing Html with razor view engine

Tags: html-helper, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Is `@MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.SomeHelperThatReturnsHtml)` the prefered way of printing Html with Razor view engine?

Comment: Yes, that is the preferred way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been doing this:

```
@( new MvcHtmlString(Html.SomeHelperThatReturnsHtml) )
```

(*sorry, not at my workstation to test code.*)